# Livewire + blade reusable component

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have created a layout template using blade and then I implement that one in order to reuse a common component, but when it renders first it takes the first component value.

So, when I change my implementation in a single file it works, as it should

**layouts/input-base.blade.php**

```php
<div>
  input example
  @yield('input')
</div>
```

**text-input.blade.php**

```php
@extends('layouts.input-base')
<div>
  {{$value}}
  <input :wire:model="value">
</div>
```

**main.blade.php**

```php
<livewire:text-input :value="$user->name" model="name"/> // All compoents render this value
<livewire:text-input :value="$user->age" model="age"/>
<livewire:text-input :value="$user->info" model="info"/>
```

Comment: Can you please ask a clear question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to assign keys to your livewire components example:

```
<livewire:text-input :value="$user->name" model="name" :wire:key="user_name">
<livewire:text-input :value="$user->age" model="age" :wire:key="user_age">
<livewire:text-input :value="$user->info" model="info" :wire:key="user_info">
```

Read more on nesting livewire components from: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components#introduction

Please keep in mind that:

> Livewire components should NOT be used for extracting Blade snippets
> into separate files. For these cases, Blade includes or components are
> preferable.

Comment: Laravel key did not work for me, but use include as the docs says works fine